# Restrict an access to Heroku app

Tags: heroku

Let's say we've already deployed Heroku app and got `public` link
Are there the ways to restrict somehow GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control ingress to your service by placing the service in a Heroku Private Space. Then, at the Space configuration level, you can identify specific ingress ranges:

[image: Heroku private space configuration]

Note that Private Spaces come with additional costs that may be substantial.

Your application is always free, of course, to implement its own authentication and ingress control in code.

Comment: Thanks, @David Reed. But lets say , that our heroku app is expected to be invoked from 3d party app and it isnt possible to set ip ranges up. What can we do in this case? Of cause we are not able to provide some extra header values etc

Comment: You can write code in your application to enforce whatever authentication mechanism you prefer. My answer is from the Heroku perspective; I can't speak to your specific stack and architecture.